# Override iOS asset catalog colors in code

Tags: ios, asset-catalog

I am developing an app with the primary BG color 'green' and 'white' as FG (e.g. for buttons). I'd like the user to select "blue" as primary color (and also pick their very own). My algorithms already compute other colors (e.g. light and dark for buttons and gradients, even shadow colors) from the given base color.

I would like to select/choose colors from the Xcode Interface Builder (through defining them in an asset catalog). User-level overridden colors should not be loaded from the real asset catalog but be retrieved by querying my code.

Now the idea: Can I override some class that will allow me to return a UIColor according to the user's choice? I thought it could work like this:

```
@implementation MyOverriddenAssets

- (UIColor*)colorForName:(NSString* const)name {
  if ([@"primary_color" isEqualToString:name]) {
    if (self.userPrimaryColor == nil) {
      return [super colorForName:name];
    } else {
      return self.userPrimaryColor;
    }
  }
}

@end
```

And somewhere else I'd probably have to register my custom catalog:

```
[assets registerCustomAssetCatalog:[MyOverriddenAssets new]];
```

I am looking for the class to override and the method name for '-colorForName:'. Searching the Apple docs was not successful, so far.

Anyone an idea, except for `Use multiple targets with custom catalogs.`? My App is single-target and should offer the option of choosing a custom color for reasons of the user's aesthetics and/or visual impairment.

Comment: Yes, you will be able to do this. But it’s not about storing values in an asset catalog. You would need to store the selected colours to disk so that you can access them when you need them (and between app launches). This could be done with something like userDefaults or CoreData etc…

Comment: I want to be able to select the primary colors from Xcode interface builder and let the user select his override value. (going to update the question)